# Upstart Sidekiq "env must be KEY=VALUE"

Tags: sidekiq, upstart

I want to use an upstart for background sidekiq process. I referred to the following link to configure a sidekiq upstart

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/upstart/manage-many/sidekiq.conf

And then when i run the command, sudo service

sudo start sidekiq path/to/myproject index=0

I get **env must be KEY=VALUE**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

path/to/project needs to change to app=path/to/project. So:

```
sudo start sidekiq app=path/to/myproject index=0
```

Comment: Thanx. I cannot believe i missed such a small thing